# Showing only rows with a fixed length of number

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like to only showing rows with a fixed length

I have several rows with client's number, and by the national length all the telephones number must only have 11 characters, but I have some data with 8 characters, or even with only zeros.

And I need to show, only those rows with 11 characters in it, and don't show the rest of the data

Like this:
[image]

My code would be like this:

```
SELECT
  Codclie
, Descrip AS [Name]
, SUBSTRING(Telef,1,11) AS [Telephone] 
, CAST(FechaE AS DATE) AS [first sale]
FROM
WHERE
    Telef <> ''
    AND
    Telef NOT LIKE ('00%')
ORDER BY
CAST(FechaE AS DATE) DESC
```

Comment: Have you looked up a length() function for your dbms? Something like: ... and len(telef) = 11

Comment: But I don´t desire to change or update anything in the database configuration, that's why I'm only querying the data

Comment: That's precisely what I said. Add [and len(telef) = 11] to your where statement.

Comment: I too, don't see why `LEN` wouldn't work here.

Comment: if you want to excluded leading zeros you could convert to BIGINT.   For example:  Select len(try_convert(bigint,'00123456789'))

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

An underscore `_` matches a single character when used with string operator/function such as `like` or `patindex`. To make sure the phone numbers must start with a number between 1-9 followed by exactly 10 more characters, you could do

```
where patindex('[1-9]_________',telef) = 1
```

If you have non-numeric characters, then you might want to add another condition to make you're filtering for numbers only

```
and try_cast(telef as int) is not null
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a temp table

```
SELECT
  Codclie
, Descrip AS [Name]
, SUBSTRING(Telef,1,11) AS [Telephone] 
, CAST(FechaE AS DATE) AS [first sale]
into #temp
FROM
WHERE
    Telef <> ''
    AND
    Telef NOT LIKE ('00%')
ORDER BY
CAST(FechaE AS DATE) DESC
```

Then delete whatever you want from the temp table

```
DELETE FROM #temp WHERE LEN(Telephone) > 7
```

Then simply select * from #temp

Comment: Why not just another `WHERE` condition? Why is a temp table necessary?

Comment: Presumably, if a simple WHERE condition solved the issue they wouldn't be posting it on SO

Comment: I'm afraid I don't hold your optimism: most questions on [so] are actually simple. This can quite clearly be implemented with a simple `WHERE`, and you have just shown that excpet you've added an intervening temp table, which seems entirely unnecessary